# JPA generate Entity from DB converts BigInt to String

Tags: spring, eclipse, jpa, entity

So I got Eclipse setup with the STS plugin after my previous slightly upset post about STS, sorry to all :)

I configured a database connection to a MySQL DB. I converted my Spring Boot Project to a JPA project in order to generate Entities from my DB Tables using JPA Tools.

What is really funny is this:
My primary key field in my table is setup as BIGINT(20), but when doing the JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables, my BIGINT primary key field gets defined as a String in the Entity and not as type long which I expected.

```
attendee_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
```

gets converted to:

```
private String attendeeId;
```

Any idea why?